# Gradle Plugin Copy task: programmatically copy files from one folder to other

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm working on porting a maven plugin to gradle plugin. I'm facing issues with a scenario where I want to copy some yaml files from a directory to a directory in build directory. Source Yaml fragments can contain property placeholders like this:

```sh
metadata:
  name: ${project.artifactId}
data:
  application.properties: |
    # spring application properties file
    welcome = Hello from Kubernetes ConfigMap!!!
    dummy = some value
```

Files need to be processed before getting copied to destination folder. This is how it's maven equivalent looks like in maven plugin: [ResourceMojo.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jkube/blob/master/kubernetes-maven-plugin/plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jkube/maven/plugin/mojo/build/ResourceMojo.java#L374). I read about gradle's copy task but when I add it no files get copied:

```java
private File[] gradleFilterFiles(File[] resourceFiles, File outDir) throws IOException {
  // ...

  File[] ret = new File[resourceFiles.length];
  int i = 0;
  for (File resource : resourceFiles) {
    File targetFile = new File(outDir, resource.getName());
    Copy copy = getProject().getTasks().create("copyJKubeFragment" + i, Copy.class);
    copy.into(outDir.toPath());
    copy.from(resource.toPath());
    ret[i++] = targetFile;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

When I build plugin and run it in a test project no files get copied:

```sh
external-resources : $ ls src/main/jkube/
configmap.yml  deployment.yml  sa.yml  service.yml
external-resources : $ gradle k8sResource
> Task :k8sResource FAILED
k8s: Running in Kubernetes mode
...
BUILD FAILED in 866ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
external-resources : $ ls build/jkube/
external-resources : $
```

I think this can some misconfiguration from my side but so far I haven't been able to figure out. I have tried with various examples of Copy task following [this link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/fdks/?api=org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy) but no files get copied. You can check out full code here: [KubernetesResourceTask.java](https://github.com/rohanKanojia/jkube/blob/pr/issue837/gradle-plugin/kubernetes/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jkube/gradle/plugin/task/KubernetesResourceTask.java#L74).

I would appreciate if someone could review this and point out what configuration of Copy task I'm missing.

Comment: Can please describe how this task will be configured within a Gradle build file?

Comment: Hi, this scenario comes into place when user adds some yaml files in configured source directory `src/main/jkube`. There may not be any explicit configuration needed. I just want them to be copied to `build/jkube` whenever they are present. You can check this reproducer for my current problem: https://github.com/r0haaaan/jkube-spring-boot-gradle-external-resources